# Testing Number.prototype with Mocha

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

Let's say I have a function on Javascript's Number prototype as follows:

controllers/index.js

```
Number.prototype.adder = function(num) {
    return this+num;
}
module.exports = Number;
```

However, the following Mocha/Chai tests are failing

```
var expect= require("chai").expect;
var CustomAdder= require("../controller/index.js");
describe("adder", function () {
    var one= 4;
    var two= 5;

    it("should add 4 and 5 to 9", function(done){
        expect(one.CustomAdder(5)).to.equal(9);
        done();
    });


    it("should not add 5 and 6 to 11", function(done){
        expect(two.CustomAdder(6)).to.not.equal(12);
        done();
    });

});
```

Error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

I am pretty sure that the problem is caused by the module.exports = Number part.
So basically my question is- how do I export a function in Number.prototype to make it testable as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is called adder, so you should do

```
expect(one.adder(5)).to.equal(9);
```

Instead of

```
expect(one.CustomAdder(5)).to.equal(9);
```

Comment: That "duh" moment :\
Accepted.